# Autodesk Forge OAuth using AngularJS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present

Tags: angularjs, oauth, autodesk-forge

I'm running a test site built on AngularJS and am having issues trying to getting Forge OAuth going.  Here's the request I'm trying to make...

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
   data: 'client_id=' + token.clientId + '&client_secret=' + token.secret + '&grant_type:client_credentials&scope=data:read',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
   withCredentials: false
}).then(function (r) {
   authToken = r.access_token;
   toastr.success('success');
}, function (e) {
   toastr.error('fail');
});
```

It's erroring out with:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I know this is a CORS related issue, which I'm not an expert about.  Is this not possible using $http.post()?  If not, how should I go about authenticating using Angular?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you call your $http from the angular client side. Whether the call is successful or not, I need to mention here that it is a bad idea to share your client id and secret in your code. Anyone can read javascript code and stole your keys - once they do that, they can use them to request an access token and use your account to process files - and you'll pay the bill. This is valid for any WEB services - free or paid - such as Twitter, google maps, etc... Never, ever, compromise your keys on the client side. Use an endpoint on your server instead.

Now, I believe there is an error your data string formatting:

```
data: 'client_id=' + token.clientId + '&client_secret=' + token.secret + '&grant_type:client_credentials&scope=data:read',
```

should probably be

```
data: 'client_id=' + token.clientId + '&client_secret=' + token.secret + '&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read',
```

grant_type:   =>   grant_type=

For the CORS issue, this is because you are calling the http request for this endpoint from the browser. Watch for the Origin header sent by your browser, you'll see that it is something specific. Once you'll get the Authorization header, the CORS issue will go away.

Hope that helps,